# Platform specifc assets folders in Android App bundle's

Tags: android-app-bundle, bundletool

The question pertains to platform specific assets that are not libraries (eg .so's). (For example a interop script generated for a specific platform, is platform specific but not a .so)

I created an Android App Bundle (aab) which has the following folder structure

```
base\assets\arm64-v8a\somefiles.py
base\assets\armeabi.v7a\somefiles.py
base\assets\x86\somefiles.py
base\assets\x86_64\somefiles.py
```

Additionally I have

```
base\lib\**\*.so
```

setup in the same way for the `so` libs.

When I run `java -jar bundletool-1.0.0.jar build-apks --bundle=somebundle.aab  --output=somebundle.apks`  (this example is stripped of signing args) and examine its output:

The `base-master*apk` contains the assets platform specific files.
I had hoped they would be in the `base-$PLATFORM*.apk`'s

For example base.master.apk
has the folders:

`assets\arm64-v8a\somefiles.py`
`assets\armeabi-v8a\somefiles.py`

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/app-bundle-format) about aabs-

"res/, lib/, and assets/: These directories are identical to those in a typical APK. When you upload your app bundle, Google Play inspects these directories and packages only the files that satisfy the target device configuration, while preserving file paths."

I assuming `bundletool` works in the same was `Google Play`.

If so why is it not behaving as the doc suggest it should?

UPDATE: I tested with a new version of bundle tool '1.15.6' just to rule that out.

UPDATE: To rule problem with my AAB I created a simple test app using Android Studio and created a AAB from that with platform specific folders in assets.

[image]

As expected this creates files in the `aab` created from Android Studio.

```
base\assets\arm64-v8a\test64.py
base\assets\armebi-v7a\test32.py
```

however a call to `java -jar bundletool-all.jar build-apks ...` still puts all these .py files in splits\base-master*.apk

Answer (score 0):

Comparing bundletool code, for `lib` and `assets` folder handling

`lib` uses `NativeDirectoryTargeting` builder

[image]

while `asset` doesn't which suggests that nothing in the 'assets' folder is split by platform.

Additional the only place I found `Targeting.NativeDirectoryTargeting.newBuilder()` usage was processing the `lib` folder. Which suggest that despite what I understood from the docs, **the** `lib` **folder is the only thing that gets split by platform**.